# Neo4j cypher query get all nodes between a start and end node including

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a model of Route/Stops(Rail/Bus)/Operators and trying to find a route by specifying the start/end stop. When I run the below query I am getting an extra stop node ("PUD") which I think should not be included in the result!! Appreciate if you let me know why the "PUD" is included and whether this is a right approach or not?

```
MATCH p = (a:Station)-[r:Goto|Operates|HasStop|Changeto*0..]-(c:Station) 
WHERE (a.name='LDS' AND 234 IN a.time) 
AND c.name='MVC' 
RETURN p
```

Model: [image: Model]

Result: [image: Result]

Comment: cypher will find all of the paths from `a` to `c` in your picture.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is matching multiple paths in against your sample diagram. Because your query has multiple relationship types allowed in the match, the query is undirected and does not specify a shorted path, it will literally find every combination of relationships that get from `a` to `c` in your model.

If you were to change the query so it only matches `Goto` and `Changeto` relationship types then you would get the result you are looking for.

Alternatively, if you made your query directed or used `shortestPath` you would also get the result you are seeking.

```
MATCH p =(a:Station)-[r:Goto|Changeto*0..]-(c:Station)
WHERE (a.name='LDS' AND 234 IN a.time) 
AND c.name='MVC' 
RETURN p
```

Directed...

```
MATCH p = (a:Station)-[r:Goto|Operates|HasStop|Changeto*0..]->(c:Station) 
WHERE (a.name='LDS' AND 234 IN a.time) 
AND c.name='MVC' 
RETURN p
```

ShortestPath...

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((a:Station)-[r:Goto|Operates|HasStop|Changeto*0..]-(c:Station))
WHERE (a.name='LDS' AND 234 IN a.time) 
AND c.name='MVC' 
RETURN p
```